# How to detect or intercept every network call made by third party app in mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, security, network-programming

In web browser we are able to detect network call in devTool/Network, So similar to that is there anyway to detect network call made by third party apps in my android/iOS device?

I have total control over my network as well as my device. Lets imagine two cases.

1) I don't have any idea about reverse engineering the source code of an app, and just wanted to capture all network calls happened in runtime environment. Is there any possibility to use network sniffer/packet sniffer like wireshark?

2) I know ways to reverse engineering an app to certain level using libraries/tool [like this](https://www.allysonomalley.com/2018/08/10/ios-pentesting-tools-part-1-app-decryption-and-class-dump/) and want to extract the possible network calls which may happen when I would run the app. Is there any way or someone has done it?

The motivation behind this activity is to detect network calls done by third party apps which contains payload which is not given permission(my browser cache/history/cookies etc).

Also let me know in comments if I need to add anything more in the question text.

Comment: Just create a VPN and intercept the request for every single network call? If you want to go further and MIMT the packet then probably need to have own certificate installed to rewrite the request. Reverse engineering to extract network call is way too much, and everyone write differently. All the adblocker VPN/sniffer app are using this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various tools like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [charles proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) that can help you with intercepting the calls.

Basically, for this, you would need to set up a proxy to your computer on your mobile device which will redirect all your network calls from your mobile device to your computer and then to the internet. Thus, your computer will be able to get the network call data.

Some apps have implemented SSL pinning. So when your laptop will act as a proxy in between, those network calls will fail, but I believe you will still get the data they wanted to send to the server.

Comment: can I use Fiddler?

Comment: yes i guess https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS

Comment: you must close the question by accepting the answer if it is resolved

Comment: sure just let me finish installation, if some another doubt arise. I may need your help. Thanks for sharing the answer.

Comment: Yes it workes very fine.  I was able to achieve the desired results using fiddler.

Comment: There is one problem I am facing right now. I have changed my system (microsoft Os) proxy to an IP belonging to USA, but when I do ipconfig, or check the IP of my system in fiddler, It is internal IP. Now I have changed the manual proxy to that internal IP. And I am trying to debug one app (which checks if traffic is from USA or not, and thats why I changed my system proxy), until login and Authentication I am able to get the all HTTPS traffic but once the auth is done, the app crashes saying something not right. I think it is because we tinkered with IP.